# real example for <track kind="chapters">

Tags: html, element

Coud anyone show me the real example, when used "chapter" value in "track" element. If you could, please help me.

I try in my server this example, but it doesn't show any result`

```
 <body> 

<video width= "500" height= "400" controls>
    <source src= "html-lesson.mp4" type= "video/mp4">
    <track src="html-lesson-hy.vtt" kind= "chapters" srclang= "hy" label= "Armenian">
    <track src="html-lesson-en.vtt" kind= "chapters" srclang= "en" label= "English" default>
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two really great resources for learning modern HTML:

- MDN, which has [a page about the `track` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track).
- The ["HTML Living Standard"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/), which goes into a lot of detail, but can give insight into how certain features work. MDN links directly to [the standard's description of the `track` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-track-element).

From this, we can learn two things:

- Firstly, the valid value for the "kind" attribute is "chapters", not "chapter".
- Secondly, the standard describes this track kind as "Chapters metadata", noting it is "Tracks intended for use from script. Not displayed by the user agent."

So, you need to correct your HTML, and then write some additional script to make use of the chapter data.

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug in the spec. MDN says *“Chapter titles are intended to be used when the user is navigating the media resource.”*, but the spec says in one place: *“Tracks intended for use from script. Not displayed by the user agent. ”* however elsewhere it says: *“and for text tracks whose kind is chapters, the user agent is making available to the user a mechanism by which the user can navigate to any point in the media resource by selecting a cue.”*

Answer (score 1):

Please use `kind="chapters"` instead of `chapter`. You can use this link to know more about it. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_track.asp

Comment: Although W3Schools is not nearly as bad as it used to be, I would strongly recommend you explore [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) which is generally much more comprehensive.